# Super resolution photos for phones with dual cameras?

Tags: camera

Is it possible to use Android phones that have a dual camera system to combine both images to come out with a higher level of resolution and less noise?

And is there already an app/program that can do this?

Comment: You should probably be aware that not all dual-cam systems work the same way. 2 major configurations are color + B/W (to enhance night performance) and normal + wide-angle (to offer optical zoom). In both configs, the secondary camera does not capture the same type of image as the main one, and isn't even used in the majority of situations.

Comment: In my case, both cameras have the same focal length and aperture. Difference being the megapixels and one being designed for low light capabilities.